# Const keyword in assignment operator chaining

Tags: c++

What is the significance of the const keyword here?
Doesnt this prevent the ability to chain = operator?
So for example, a=b=c,
a=b is evaluated first then (result of (a=b)=c), but according to the below definition its result is immutable and from the definition below would modify the return value in (a=b=c)

or maybe i just dont understand

```
const SimpleCircle & SimpleCircle::operator=(const SimpleCircle & rhs)
{
    if(this == &rhs)
       return *this;
    itsRadius = rhs.getRadius();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: The only `const` here is the const reference argument, and I don't see where you think it's modified.

Comment: Oh crap hahahahaha forgot to put it in hahahahahahahaha

Comment: *"a=b is evaluated first then (result of (a=b)=c)"* [oh yeah?](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9wvIQ2ivvobBQteN)

Comment: @Jokaaa ...because it's not there in a canonical implementation?

Comment: WHY NEG THOUGH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a chain `a=b=c` with this operator, the result of the first assignment (`b=c`) is going to be the argument of the second (`a=b`), which expects a `const&` as well.

So no problem with the chain here.

Comment: Ah right, there was a confusion with the evaluation sequence.

Comment: I was looking at cout << x << y, and thought the evaluation sequence would be the same for something like a = b = c, but thanks for that

Comment: For something like c = c + b, is c+b evaluated first then c = result of (c+b)?

Comment: yes, of course. Otherwise, nothing would work in C++ ;)